# Convert column of numbers to integer openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm getting data from 1 file to another with openpyxl. 1 column contains numbers formatted as text but I want to convert the full column without the header into integer. I managed to do it for 1 cell and I don't manage to do my loop in order to convert all cells.
I tried to loop on the cell 'A + i' to go through all cells but the int() functions doesn't accept it.

Below is the code working and getting all the data and converting only the cell A2:
*(I use the first part of the loop as I'm getting values from different columns.)*

```
for i in range(2, 6000):
    # Case_ID
    cell_range1 = ws1.cell(i,6)
    cell_range2 = ws2.cell(i,1)
    cell_range2.value = cell_range1.value

    ws2['A2'] = int(ws2['A2'].value)
```

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
for i in range(2, 6000):
    # Case_ID
    # value of cell from worksheet 1
    ws1_cell_value = ws1.cell(row=i, column=6).value
    
    # convert ws1 value and set ws2 cell value
    ws2.cell(row=i, column=1).value = int(ws1_cell_value)
```

I made a test file and it works as expected. Full code below:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

# make test file
wb1 = Workbook()
ws1 = wb1.active
for x in range(2, 6000):
    ws1.cell(row=x, column=6).value = f"{x}"

wb1.save('string_column.xlsx')

# out file
wb2 = Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active

# ACTUAL ANSWER CODE:
for i in range(2, 6000):
    # Case_ID
    # value of cell from worksheet 1
    ws1_cell_value = ws1.cell(row=i, column=6).value
    
    # convert ws1 value and set ws2 cell value
    ws2.cell(row=i, column=1).value = int(ws1_cell_value)
    
   
wb2.save('int_column.xlsx')
```